# How to route/extract different columns from a single CSV file in Nifi?

Tags: apache, csv, apache-nifi

I have a GetFile processor which fetches a large CSV file that has about a 100 columns. My goal is to extract specific subsets of columns from this CSV file and send them to various different tables in MySQL.

The current approach makes use of **GetFile** -> Multiple **ConvertRecord** Processors where in there are different **CSVReader** and **CSVRecordSetWriters** defined, which abide to the AVRO schemas based on the SQL table's schema.

Is there a way to have only one GetFile and Route the subsets to different processors as opposed to replicating the large CSV file across multiple flows, which then get picked up by different ConvertRecord processors?

This is the flow I have right now,
[image: Multiple Queues of Large Files]

As can be seen, the CSV file replicates across multiple paths and makes things very inefficient. For this example the size is 57bytes, but usually I get ~6 GB Files across 60-70 such **ConvertRecord** paths

How can I efficiently route my data if I am aware of which subsets of columns need to be extracted from the CSV file and sent to different tables? Example:

Column **A,B** go to one table

Column **A,C** go to the second table

Column **A,D,E** go to the third table

Column **A,D,F,G** go to the third table
....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use PutDatabaseRecord then you can have multiple PutDatabaseRecord processors that each use a different read schema to select the appropriate columns, similar to what you are doing with the ConvertRecord processors, but you never actually need to write out the converted data.

Also, there is nothing really inefficient about forking the same flow file to 6 different locations. In your example above, if GetFile picks up a 6GB file, there is only 1 copy of that 6GB content in the content repository and there would be 3 flow files pointing to that same content, so each ConvertRecord would read the same 6GB content. Then they would each write out a new piece of content which would be a subset of the data, and at some point original 6GB would be deleted from the content repo when no flow files referenced it. So its not like every additional connection from GetFile is making a copy of the 6GB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still learning how to best utilize nifi for high file size data flows that bring together a very large file in different flows and does various etl operations on them before throwing them to a database. How would you say is the best way to configure nifi to allow such a flow to happen?

Comment: The main thing is to use record-oriented processors and avoid splitting up the records into many small flow files which will lead to poor performance